# Can i export BUS routes from OpenStreetMap as shapefiles to work on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, export

The OSM has all the routing for the buses in my city, even showing the ID of the bus if you zoom close enough. I know how to download the shapefiles with the roads, rails, etc., from Geofabrik, but the bus routing isn't included there.

If I can't get access to this routes in ArcMap, I'll have to draw them one by one, which doesn't make that much sense since that work has already been done. Please, can someone help me?

Comment: Bus routes are available with routing info from http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Lissabon/ shapefile format will be your best bet for arcgis.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to access the routing info? I've downloaded the shape files but none of them seem to have this data. Maybe they're not included in shape files?

Comment: Conver to File Geodatabase and use the Network Analysis so the at ArcGIS can build your routes.

Answer (score 2):

When you need some kind of special or selective data from openstreetmap it's always a good idea to reach them via [overpass](http://overpass-turbo.eu/). Here is a piece of code to get lines of route=bus

```
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
  <union>
    <query type="relation">
      <has-kv k="route" v="bus"/>
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
    <recurse type="relation-way"/>
    <recurse type="way-node"/>
  </union>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

This [link](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/3gl) will take you stright to the site with filled query - all you have to do is scroll the map to desired area, run the query and export results to file.